# running protractor with internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've been writing tests using protractor lately and I have been unable to run my tests using IE 11. I am able to run protractor using firefox and chrome with no problems but when using IE 11 I get the following error.

```
 I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
 I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
 E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see launcher
 E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I don't know what this error refers to and I was unable to find anything useful when doing a google search. I have already installed the IE driver for protractor but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried removing the driver and installing it again but no luck. I found other threads on SO with similar issues but they seemed to be resolved by installing or re-installing the IE driver. This is my config file which I can run with other browsers.

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        //name: 'firefox',
        //'browserName': 'firefox'
        //name: 'internet explorer',
        'browserName': 'Internet Explorer',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': '11'
     }
    ],
onPrepare: function () {
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: 'testresults',
        filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
    }));
},
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: true,
    realtimeFailure: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
},
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
suites: {
    AESpecs: ['featureSpecs/appExperience.detailed.featureSpec.js']    
 }
}
```

If anything, I'm running win 7 64-bit. I know someone else running win 10 64-bit and was able to get it running with no issues.

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit IEdriver?  64-bit has some issues.  Also I think it should be uncapitalized `internet explorer` in config but not sure if that actually matters.

Comment: try following:
1. Update ie using - 'webdriver-manager update --ie'
2. Change you capabilities to - 
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': '11'
    },

And  try it once

Comment: I tried the above suggestions before and and still the same results

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **Protractor 4.0.0**, the `uncaught exception` which you are observing is not the correct error message, the error which you are facing could be due to various reasons mostly due to exceptions in promise control flow. It was not handled properly in that version of protractor. It has been resolved with later versions of protractor.

Please upgrade or downgrade the version so that you would know the exact `error/exception` which is causing your scripts to fail in IE browser!